# how can I track down which module is causing a require.paths error?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I've got a simple coffee script web server set up:

```
http = require 'http'
express = require 'express'

http.createServer (req, res) ->
        res.writeHead 200
        res.end 'Hello, World!'
.listen 8888

console.log 'Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8888/'
```

When I run this, it's fine and serving pages:

```
~/jsfinder> coffee app.coffee
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```

OK no problems there. But when I try the same with nodemon I get:

```
~/jsfinder> nodemon app.coffee

Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
    at Function.Module._compile.Object.defineProperty.get (module.js:386:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/bin/nodemon@0.6.12:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

So this is either a bug in nodemon or one of my modules in my npm globals is actually using require.paths. I'm going with the latter. Thing is, I have about 12 modules installed globally, so should I just grep them all and find it that way? Or does that exception stack trace tell me something that I'm not seeing? Does this look like a legit bug in nodemon?

I ran an `npm update -g` with no issues this morning, so all my modules should be up to date.

Update: did some grepping in the node modules directory with no results:

```
/usr/lib/nodejs/npm/node_modules> find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep require.paths
/usr/lib/nodejs/npm/node_modules> cd ..
/usr/lib/nodejs/npm> find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep require.paths
/usr/lib/nodejs/npm> cd ..
/usr/lib/nodejs> find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep require.paths
./module.js:    throw new Error('require.paths is removed. Use ' +
```

And:

```
~/jsfinder> find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep require.paths
~/jsfinder>
```

So that's telling me that no module in globals or locals is using require.paths. **Confusing**.

Comment: Does it work if you do the same sample with pure Node.js (without CoffeeScript) ?

Comment: @HectorCorrea nope, I tried the node version of hello world and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the former and would be willing to bet that the error is in `nodemon@0.6.12:4:21` :)

I don't think your update command worked, since `nodemon` should be `@0.6.23`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that text was out of date. After I copied it I did a global update, then re-ran the app and got the same result.

Comment: I will, but I'm 99% certain that the stack trace is identical, except version numbers.

Comment: how strange, the stack trace still says 0.6.12 even though npm says nodemon is at 0.6.23; I did a full uninstall of all my modules when I was trying to track this down. Seems something didn't go right. Stack trace line: ' at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/bin/nodemon@0.6.12:4:21)'

Comment: This answer got me on the right track: somehow there was an old version of nodemon in my /home/user/bin and my nodemon command was pointing to that instead. Not sure how it got there, maybe a weird nodemon install? Anyway, deleting that and pointing it to the right place took care of it.

Comment: glad you found the rogue nodemon!